# Get total of numbers inside group of elements

Tags: jquery

OK so I have some share buttons for various social media channels basically marked up as follows:

```
<a href="[sharelink]">
<img src="[buttonsrc]" />
</a>
<span class="share-counter">
[number of shares]
</span>
```

...repeated 5 times

This is probably best done with jQuery, basically what I want to do is get the total shares, i.e. the total of the numbers held within all the .share-counter elements and place that number inside an element called, lets say .share-total

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to to sum them up

```
var total = 0;
$('.share-counter').each(function () {
    total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
});
$('.share-total').text(total)
console.log(total)
```